"network-config" on another reboot (not first boot) to apply and update wifi settings
I use a "network-config" file on a "system-boot" partition (as created by Raspberry Imager) for Ubuntu Server (headless install) to define wifi settings.
Now I lost the connection because the wifi settings changed.
However that file is only read after first boot as described in the header comment:
# This file contains a netplan-compatible configuration which cloud-init
# will apply on first-boot. [...]


How can I enforce it to be read again, having only access to the microSD card (where the operating system is installed) ?
Or is there an alternative that I can add a new wifi connection by modifying a file on the disk?
I have only physical access to the installation medium (operating system on microSD card), no ssh.

It is known that one can modify /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml and run sudo netplan apply as described in
 How to install Ubuntu Server on your Raspberry Pi  - 4. Boot Ubuntu Server.
However, without access to the device, one cannot run that command, but only edit the file.
